# Return anonymous object from a method in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I return an anonymous object from a method in ruby.?

In the following code, I am returning an hash.

```
  def process
    source = helper

    # I am able to get the value as an hash
    puts source[:url]
    puts source[:params]

    # But I wonder if there is a way to get it as an object, so that I can use the dot notation
    # puts source.url
    # puts source.params
  end

  def helper
    url = ''
    params = ''
    return {url: url, params: params}
  end
```

Any thoughts.?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Objects in Ruby don't have names, they are always anonymous. In your code, you *are* returning an anonymous object, namely a `Hash`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Openstruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)?

```
require 'ostruct'

def helper
  OpenStruct.new(url: '', params: '')    
end
```

Comment: Thanks.! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
def helper
  Class.new do
    def url
      ''
    end
    def params
      ''
    end
  end.new
end
```